# Is it rude to ask an adviser at my current university to help me transfer?

Tags: etiquette, transfer-student

I'm an undergraduate looking into transferring from my current university to another college overseas, the application for which requires a letter of motivation detailing why I want to study there. The problem with this is that my reasons for transferring basically boil down to "this college is cheaper and seems to care more about its students than my current university".

My current university offers help with application essays for undergraduates applying to law and medical school, and I really think that this service could help me write a decent letter of motivation. I'm just wondering if it's rude to go to an adviser at my current university and essentially ask him to help me transfer to another university. I've met the adviser before and he jokingly critiques my current school quite a bit, but if I go to him for help, I will basically be talking to him about how much I hate his place of employment. Any advice?

Comment: In my experience, it is usually better to focus on the positives of where you're going, rather than the negatives of where you're leaving. Most people will be responsive to that, and (depending on your relationship with him) you adviser would probably be happy to help if you framed it in that way.

Comment: Most people are understanding of others' situations, just talk to him! People transfer or drop out all the time.

Answer (score 3):

You have think this matter in a practical way.
You should not tell your advisor that the reasons linked to your transfer are linked to the fact that you prefer the other one. In my experience, you should be diplomatic, focus on what is important, saying that this would be a good opportunity for having new experiences, specially in terms of academia. You should express your genuine will to grow as a student.

Moreover, I believe that you should not fear your advisor. If he becomes rude or irritated or whatever, it is not your fault because nothing justifies aggressiveness

So, this is a risk you will have to take in order to take a chance and try to go wherever you want to go. This is kind of the part of being an adult and dealing with stressful situations in life, specially in academia.

Good luck and don't waste your time overthinking this.